# Calling setState() in React from render method

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to reset React state variables (to default values) in a container using setState() method. But getting the following error

```
 Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition 
(such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods 
 should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, 
 but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.
```

And finally: Maximum call stack size exceeded.

My code below:

```
resetMsg=()=>  {  
const company = this.state.company;
company.id = 0;
company.messages = [];    
this.setState({company: company});       
}
```

I am calling resetMsg() when variable in Redux state is true.

Code where I call resetMsg (The value of resetMessages is false initially and I need to reset React-state, when its true ):

```
    render() {
    if(this.props.resetMessages){           
        this.resetMsg();           
    }
```

Comment: do not setstate in render method as it will rerender and it will be a infinite loop

Comment: ca you post where you call this resetMsg() ?

Comment: @Jeffin  Any suggestion on how to reset values?

Comment: better call setState in componentWillMount or componentWillReceiveProps, not in render. you are creating an infinity loop by calling setState in render. because of the state change, the component renders again. you might want taking a look at the react lifecycle methods: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You might want to look into `componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)` function. As per the official docs:

> `componentWillReceiveProps()` is invoked before a mounted component receives new props. If you need to update the state in response to prop changes (for example, to reset it), you may compare this.props and nextProps and perform state transitions using this.setState() in this method.

This is where you want to do the resets. So something like:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if(nextProps.resetMessages) {
    const company = Object.assign({}, this.state.company);
    company.id = 0;
    company.messages = [];    
    this.setState({company: company});
  }
}
```

The snippet above will run every time props are sent down to the component. It first checks if the `resetMessages` prop is truthy. If it is, it will create a temporary copy of the `company` state, change the `id` and `messages` property values, and then update `company` with the new one.

---

I want to highlight the issues you had with your code:

1. Calling `setState()` inside `render()` is a no-no.

   Whenever you call `setState()` in general the `render()` will be run afterwards. Doing so inside `render()` itself will cause that function to be called again, and again, and again...
2. Mutating the state and/or props directly.

   This line `const company = this.state.company;` does not create a copy of the state variable. It only store the *reference* to it. So once you do this, and then do `company.id = ...` you are essentially doing `this.state.company.id = ...`, which is anti-pattern in React. We only ever change state through `setState()`.

   To create a copy, use `Object.assign({}, this.state.yourObject)` for objects and `this.state.yourArray.slice()` for arrays.

Comment: @user8125765, you are welcome. Check the comments I added in my edit.

Comment: @Chris You have the method name misspelled as "componentWillRecieveProps" in your first sentence (though it is correct everywhere else).

Answer (score 13):

[componentWillReceiveProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops) is **deprecated** now (since June'18)

You should use one of the alternatives presented in the [react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops) instead.

In your case I guess it could be justified to use the 'not so recommended' alternative 1 version that uses [getDerivedStateFromProps](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#alternative-1-reset-uncontrolled-component-with-an-id-prop), as you are just recomputing the state vars:

```
getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
  if(props.resetMessages) {
    const company = Object.assign({}, state.company);
    company.id = 0;
    company.messages = [];    
    return {
      company: company
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try delaying the `setState()` call until the rendering completes. You can use `setTimeout()` for this purpose. For example, instead of:

```
this.resetMsg()
```

use

```
setTimeout(() => this.resetMsg())
```

This will push the `resetMsg()` call (and hence the `setState()`, too) to the end of the event queue, letting the `render()` call complete first.